# Why does my admin page appear corrupted after using Backup and Migrate?

Tags: 8, backups

I recently restored a site backup using the Backup and Migrate plugin. Now my admin toolbar looks like this.

Flushing cache does nothing. How can I fix this?

[image: corrupted admin page]

Comment: Flush cache, disable aggregation, check RewriteBase in htaccess, run cron, flush cache, and flush cache again. Of course also check watchdog (logs) and status site. Not to forget files/ folder permissions and ownership. Aaaaand flush cache again (yes also your Browser cache). 

Answer (score 1):

If you forget to preserve the file permissions when restoring a backup, you'll run into this. Make sure you use tar's `p` flag when you extract the backup file. Run `drush ws` to see watchdog error logs and you'll find permission errors like this:

```
------ -------------- ------ ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID     Date           Type   Severity   Message
 ------ -------------- ------ ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3436   26/May 18:43   php    Warning    User warning: mkdir(): Permission Denied in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory() (line 145 of
                                          /home/public/core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/FileStorage.php) #0 /h
```

Fix the file and directory permissions, then rebuild the cache with `drush cr` and you should see:

[image]